# Hibernate - non-working code an what is a service-registry

Tags: java, hibernate

I just got through the book "Just Hibernate" from O'Reilly. Some code isn't really explained fully but just given without complete description.
This code for example:

```
public class BasicMovieManager {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    // Creating SessionFactory using 4.2 version of Hibernate
   private void initSessionFactory(){
       Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
       // Build a Registry with our configuration properties
       ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
       config.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
       // create the session factory
       sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
}
...
}
```

I just wanted to copy the code to my Hibernate-experiments, but the current stable Hibernate-version 5.2 doesn't know the class ServiceRegistryBuilder. What is a service-registry and how do I have to change the code to work with the current Hibernate-version?

Answer (score 2):

The code was used to create a SessionFactory with Hibernate 4.x

The similar code for Hibernate 5.x would be something like:

```
    StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = 
       new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
    Metadata metaData = 
        new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
    sessionFactory = metaData.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
```

As you can see, in Hibernate 5 StandardServiceRegistry class is used. If you don't have a `hibernate.cfg.xml` file just use `configure()` method with no arguments.

See [this article](https://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/hibernate5/hibernate-5-buildsessionfactory.shtml) for further details.